# How does one peel and puree chick peas with a food mill for hummus?

Tags: hummus

Hating having to peel each individual garbanzo bean/chick pea by hand to make hummus, I read online that a food mill will press out the "meat" of the beans while leaving the skins behind. The food mill I have has three different disks - coarse, medium and fine. To make hummus from ground chick peas/garbanzo beans, which disk should I use? How often should I clear away the leftover skins?

Comment: also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/how-do-you-peel-chickpeas

Comment: @rumtscho - Yup, my search-fu was weak. The question was nicely answered in that exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Grinding the chickpeas before cooking kind of defeats the purpose. To use a food mill to its best, you shouldn't do any grinding before you cook the chickpeas.

After you cook them, they will be more accepting of grinding or other techniques. Cook them low and slow just as you would any other bean. When they are tender (and cool enough to handle), put them in the food mill. My food mill only has one coarseness, so I assume that is about medium. So, cook your chickpeas and then use a food mill with the medium blade to remove the skins and proceed with your recipe.

Comment: Cooking them was understood to be a part of the process... I'm not trying to make chickpea flour!